# Possibilities for a CSS::inner pseudo-element

Tags: css

CSS2 has the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements, which enables stylesheets to alter documents in ways that would previously require adding extra non-semantic elements to a page as "style-hooks".

I was surprised that CSS3 didn't add any `::inner` or `::outer` pseudo-element which would eliminate even more cases of HTML "divitis" - when pages contain many `<div class="wrapper">` elements, purely as style-hooks with zero semantic value. CSS3's support for multiple background images and gradients per box helps,

One recent situation involved this markup:

```
<div>
    <img src="foo.jpg" />

    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Dolor sit amet</p>
</div>

<!-- followed by the same markup template (with a different img src and paragraph text) repeated several times -->
```

The visual page design called for the `<img />` element to be positioned or floated to the side (within the constraints of the `<div>` which filled the document width, and the text and heading should have a thick border around them, but not the image.

Ideally, with a hypothetical `::inner` element, this could be solved like so:

```
div {
    display: block;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
}
div::nth-of-type(odd) { background: #FEFEFE; }

div > img {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
div::nth-of-type(odd) > img {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
}

div::inner {
    border: 5px solid #CECECE;
    max-width: 20em;
}
```

However, I had to settle on adding a wrapper element:

```
<div>
    <img src="foo.jpg" />

    <div>
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

(with the `div::inner` selector replaced with `div > div`).

I believe this could be done with Polyfill.js to handle "`::inner`" and "`::outer`" selectors by running `querySelectorAll` for the targeted elements and respectively wrapping their contents, or the elements themselves, and applying the properties to those new elements. I'm wondering if anyone has already accomplished this, or if any browsers support this functionality already as a proprietary extension - such as how IE supports multiple `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements using the `::before(n)` syntax.

Comment: How does the `::inner` knows which elements it should wrap? .. I mean in the `div > div` case it is obvious

Comment: I made a first draft here, [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/mhz8twgo/), though the absolute positioned images gave me some issues (as they take the image out of flow), so I removed the positioning for now. The draft uses a fixed image height and the pseudo the same.

Comment: As the absolute positioned image cause issues, what is the purpose having them as such?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe can be solved with `calc(...)` and a floating image, see demo here: http://codepen.io/askl/pen/zBRbJB .

```
div {
  border: 5px solid #CECECE;
  width: calc(100% - 120px);
  overflow: visible;
}

div > img:first-child {
  float: right;
  margin-right: -110px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
```

As is noted in the LGSon's comment it is not entirely clear how an `:inner` pseudo-element would help in this problem. However, I tend to agree, there are cases in practice where such pseudo-elements would be useful. May be `flexbox` is part of an answer; however, I couldn't solve your particular problem with it, an approach with simple widths and floating seems to be far easier.